# Asking questions in the imperfect tense

Tags: choix-de-mot, temps-grammatical, questions

I'm currently working in France to improve my French. I wanted to know if one of the customers at the restaurant had received their basket of bread. Since in English I would have phrased the question like, 'were you given a basket of bread', I phrased the question as *Est-ce que vous étiez donné une corbeille de pain.*' I was told this doesn't make sense but I wanted to confirm the reason. Personally, I felt it was perhaps too literal a translation or the tense was completely incorrect but am unsure. Does my question work in any context at all or it's simply not very 'French'.

I have also thought of alternatives and wondered if they were better options:

- *Est-ce que vous avez été donne une corbeille de pain?*
- *Est-ce que quelqu'un vous a déjà donné une corbeille de pain?*

Comment: The answers here are good, but I think they take a long time to get to the essential confusion. The main thing wrong with your example can be summed up in a single sentence, and it has nothing to do with tense: **You can't use the grammatical passive with an indirect object.** As such, your last alternative has the correct structure.

Comment: Please note that the title of this question is misleading. The question is about "Asking a question in the passive form". There is actually no imperfect tense used in both your examples as both are "passé composé" in addition to be passive.

Answer (score 3):

Je demanderais plus simplement :

*Vous a-t-on (déjà) donné du pain ?*

Le *est-ce que* initial n'est pas nécessaire et alourdit significativement la question.

Par ailleurs, comme observé par @Montéedelait en commentaires, *amener* ou *apporter* seraient plus à propos.

Comment: Je privilégierais personnellement *«Vous a-t’on (déjà) **amené** du pain?»*, mais +1 néanmoins pour la tournure simple et euphonique.

Comment: @Montéedelait : Absolument. ***amener*** ou encore ***apporter*** seraient effectivement plus pertinents.

Comment: Les amis, je pense que vous voulez écrire 'Vous a-t-on'…

Comment: @mcadorel : Bien vu! (Et merci!)

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in your sentence which indeed doesn't make much sense in French.

First, the right phrase is "*un**e** corbeille **de** pain*" and not "*un corbeille du pain*", but that was corrected later in your question.

The main issue is the beginning of your sentence:

> ***Est-ce que vous étiez donné*** une corbeille de pain ?

somewhat means that you were the subject of the gift instead of the recipient, but the end doesn't fit.

An idiomatic sentence would have been:

> Est-ce qu'on vous a apporté une corbeille de pain ?

or:

> Est-ce qu'on vous a apporté du pain ?

or even:

> On vous a apporté du pain ?

*Être donné* could have been used that (formal) way:

> Est-ce qu'il vous a bien été donné une corbeille de pain.

The second attempt might have been understood as a calque of English but is not proper French.

> Est-ce que vous avez été donné une corbeille de pain ?

This last sentence is correct French but depending on the context might have an alternative meaning without the right context:

> Est-ce que quelqu'un vous a déjà donné une corbeille de pain ?

Were you already given a basket of bread?

Were you ever given a basket of bread?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your sentence: 1) the use of a passive construction and the use of the "imparfait" (étiez).

the "imparfait" is used for an action in the past that is incomplete, ongoing or uncounted. You should use the "passé composé" here. See this [site](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/passe-compose-vs-imparfait/) for more details.

With the passive form, the COD (complément object direct) can become a subject, not the "compléments" that are introduces by a preposition. In French, you use

> donner quelque chose (COD) à quelqu'un (COI)

so you can say

> Quelque chose est donné à quelqu'un.

but NOT

> Quelqu'un est donné quelque chose.

For un undetermined subject, you could use

> On a donné quelque chose à quelqu'un.

or a passive form where the subject does not come from one of the "compléments"

> Il a été donné quelque chose à quelqu'un.

If you put this in your context, this could gives:

- *Est-ce qu'il vous a été donné une corbeille de pain?*
- *Est-ce qu'une corbeille de pain vous a été donnée ?*
- *Est-ce que quelqu'un/on vous a (déjà) donné une corbeille de pain?*

Personally, I prefer the third option because the two others are quite "heavy". Or, to avoid a passive form, I would reword with "recevoir" (in a way, "recevoir" is the passive counterpart of "donner").

- *Avez-vous déjà reçu une corbeille de pain?*

Comment: « Recevoir » ne s'utilise pas vraiment dans des contextes aussi banals que le service de table; par exemple on devrait trouver normal, si cela était le cas, des phrases comme « Ensuite nous avons reçu le vin. » et cela ne se dit pas; assez normalement on dit « Ensuite le vin nous a été apporté. » ou « Ensuite on nous a apporté le vin.» ou autre possibilités parmi un nombre indéfini, « Ensuite nous a été servi le vin. », « Ensuite on nous a servi le vin. ».

Comment: d'accord pour le vin (qui est servi à table) mais, en ce qui concerne le pain, je ne vois pas le problème avec "recevoir".  Je ne comprends pas le lien entre la banalité du service de table et l'utilisation (ou pas) du verbe recevoir. N'est-ce pas plutôt la spécificité du service de table qui imposerait l'utilisation de termes particuliers. L'utilisation de recevoir dans le sens "se voir donner quelque chose" me semble assez banale.

Comment: Vous diriez « recevoir l'hostie de la main du curé », je serais d'accord; ce que je crois ressentir c'est que le sens du verb « recevoir » est empreint d' une certaine solemnité, un certain formalisme traditionnel que je ne souhaite pas associer à ces chose-là (service de table); je ne trouve pas  votre définition dans le dictionnaire (TLFi); j'y trouve plusieurs définitions  proches mais pas plus : se voir attribuer qqc, se voir confier qqc, se voir transmettre qqc, se voir conférer qqc, se voir témoigner qqc,… Il est apparent que nous allons devoir différer sur ce point!